# how to split a string with delimeters '(' '{' '} ')'' in java

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

```
String str = "one(two)three{four}"
String[] arr  = str.split("(\\()(\\{)(\\))(\\}))";
```

output should be like :

```
arr = {"one","two","three","four"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex won't compile.

```
 ( \( )                        # (1)
 ( \{ )                        # (2)
 ( \) )                        # (3)
 ( \} )                        # (4)
 =    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'
```

You probably mean  to split on `[(){}]+`

Answer (score -1):

You should escape your backslashes **and** add or:

```
String str = "one(two)three{four}";    
String[] arr = str.split("\\(|\\)|\\{|\\}");
```

Or you can use the square brackets list:

```
String str = "one(two)three{four}";    
String[] arr = str.split("[(){}]");
```

Both options will work

Comment: It only looked like that because the code wasn't formatted right - the backslashes were already escaped by the OP.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt It's not only the code formatting - it's also the or operand missing - updated by answer

Answer (score -1):

If you want to capture just text part in the above string, you could use below regex;

```
(\w+)
```

Link to test [here](http://www.regextester.com/?fam=98105)

Comment: This is not how split works - you need to regex to split on - this will give you only the (,),{,} result